# how Disable "Extrude region together along the average normal"

Tags: extrude

i started to learn how use blender.
I was trying to create a bench but when i need to select the angle for extrude the surface it active the function "Extrude region together along the average normal" and select surface that i don't need to be select.[image]

Comment: Shift-Click on the face that you don't want to be extruded to deselect it before you extrude?

Comment: ok i don't really know why this time it work but hey thanks for your help

Comment: Your image showed that you had two faces selected (the orange one and the whitish one to the right of it.) I assumed that you were just trying to extrude the orange one, in which case you would Ctrl-click on the whitish one to deselect it before moving the extrude gizmo.